# Eclipse kepler can't install updates

Tags: eclipse-cdt, eclipse-kepler

After downloading updates it shows a error that can't install updates .

> An error occurred while uninstalling
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.cpp, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.eclipse.rcp.configuration_root.win32.win32.x86_64 1.0.0.v20130521-1847 --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).
>   Backup of file D:\eclipse\eclipse.exe failed.
>   Can not remove : D:\eclipse\eclipse.exe

I'm running it under win7 and jdk1.7.0_21 64bit .

How fix it ?

Comment: 1-Run eclipse
2-Rename eclipse exe to eclipse.exe.back
3-Run updates
4-Updates executed successfully

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Refer this post: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/487240/. It helped in solving this problem for me.

Shown below for your convenience :

> I had same issue with updating Kepler. W7 with admin.
>
> How to solve:
>
> Run eclipse Rename eclipse exe to eclipse.exe.back
>
> Run updates
>
> Updates executed successfully
>
> Premysl Fiala

Answer (score 24):

Solution extracted from the forum linked in Anonymous answer:

1. Run eclipse
2. Rename eclipse exe to eclipse.exe.back
3. Run updates
4. Updates executed successfully

To match so guidelines:
*Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*

Comment: thank you, this helped me upgrade from kepler  4.3.2 to luna 4.4

Comment: This also works for other Eclipse-based IDE's as well. e.g. Spring's GGTS and STS.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new workspace. Eclipse Kepler does cause a  problem if we work on the older workspace. Worked for me.