# Error while updating Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I get an error while trying to update Eclipse (Kepler Service Release 1; Build id: 20130919-0819)

Eclipse wants to update the following package:

- Eclipse Standard/SDK 2.0.2.20140224-0000

> An error occurred while uninstalling
>
> session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.eclipse.rcp.configuration_root.win32.win32.x86 1.0.0.v20130521-1847 --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).
>
> Backup of file E:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\eclipse.exe failed.
>
> Can not remove : E:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\eclipse.exe

This error also occurs when I try to update as administrator.

Does anybody have any idea what would cause this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse kepler can't install updates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427728/eclipse-kepler-cant-install-updates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The eclipse update feature seems to mess up a lot of times with broken dependencies and missing configurations.

You can fix them all up manually if you would like to but that would take some time to debug what is wrong and then how to fix it.

The best advise I can give you is to download a fresh copy of the required Eclipse version and then import your workspace in this new Eclipse installation

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I reinstalled eclipse.

Answer (score 8):

Solution extracted from this forum http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/487240/:

1. Run eclipse
2. Rename eclipse exe to eclipse.exe.back
3. Run updates
4. Updates executed successfully

It worked for me.
See [Eclipse kepler can't install updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427728/eclipse-kepler-cant-install-updates/23807425#23807425).